# How to find out compression algorithm of unknown partly compressed custom filetype without magic numbers

Tags: python, java, linux, compression

I am trying to get files from a 'firmware'-file of an embedded system.
Do not have access to the hardware to the point that I can open it up and connect a serial shell.
The hardware is probably an ARM processor with ~500Mb of RAM and the software was written between 2020 and 2022. I have access to the web interface which uses one of the common JS-frontend frameworks and lighthttpd to host this website. It has a button to check for a new firmware. The firmware is pretty well guarded and not given out to anyone, so I cannot ask them to give it out. The update mechanism works by sending a HTTP get request to a webserver which returns the 'firmware'-file. I know that the script that is downloading this file is written in Python and uses the requests library version 2.27.x. I have access to two versions of the firmware. This is the filename: firmware_00.03_01.02.14.tar.ogz - 00.03 is the hardware version and 01.02.14 the software version. I also have the 01.02.12 version of the file. If you look at the file with a hex editor you will see a header section and a data section.
[image]

[image]

The Linux file command results in nothing, binwalk results in nothing as well.
The only interesting thing I could find out until now is that the header section contains the software version and when you try to compress the file it does not save any space, so I believe the file is already compressed pretty well. I tried adding bz2 and gz magic numbers and decompressing it but python throws an exception that it is not valid bz2 or gz compressed data.
The compressed data section does not contain any strings.

Can anyone push me into the right direction here?
Is it possible to determine the compression algorithm?
I believe that the people who wrote this may have used java, Python or less likely but still - cpp. The main application running the software - other than the configuration-webinterface - is probably written in python because of what is is doing and library support.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if I can be of any help, someone  might, but you would be much better off to paste the (Linux) output of `xxd foo.bin >paste-me-as-code-formatted-txt.txt`

Comment: *so I believe the file is already compressed pretty well* that could well mean that the file format is not redundant in any way, rather than already being compressed

Comment: Why are you trying to find the algorithm? It seems that you need something else instead.

Comment: @g00se it is a file larger than 26Mb containing multiple files.

Comment: @aled because I want to extract the files contained in the compressed part.

Comment: but you don't actually know if it is compressed, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check "binwalk -E" command to check that file entropy is actually high.

You says: "The firmware is pretty well guarded and not given out to anyone". This firmware can also encrypted (encryption key can be hardcoded in device bootloader and depends on hardware version, you should physically dump flash memory to get it).

Sometimes firmware vendors uses ECB mode for encryption. You can try to detect it by finding same repeating blocks in firmware file.

If it is not encryption but compression with no signature you can try to bruteforce it like this: https://gist.github.com/nstarke/f23b018c4e0fd4c8f8ca1cd67dc2b61c.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Binwalk -E says entropy is high:  Rising entropy edge (0.987834) I guess now we know it is encrypted and/or compressed, which the file-name suggests. I now believe it is encrypted since I cannot uncompress the data with gzip even though the file name suggests it. I will still try out the decompression brute force and report back. THX